# Sign extension query in case of short

Tags: c

Given,

```
unsigned short y = 0xFFFF;
```

When I print

```
printf("%x", y);
```

I get : `0xFFFF;`

But when I print

```
printf("%x", (signed short)y);
```

I get : `0xFFFFFFFF`

Whole program below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    unsigned short y = 0xFFFF;
    unsigned short z = 0x7FFF;

    printf("%x %x\n", y,z);
    printf("%x %x", (signed short)y, (signed short)z);

    return 0;
}
```

Sign extension happens when we typecast lower to higher byte data type, but here we are typecasting short to signed short.
In both cases sizeof((signed short)y) or sizeof((signed short)z) prints 2 bytes. Short remains of 2 bytes, if sign bit is zero as in case of 0x7fff. 
Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: `%x` expects an (unsigned) **integer**? Use `%hx` for half (short) integer.

Comment: So are you saying %x is typecasting short into unsigned int, and it is happening for both printfs (printf("%x %x\n", y,z);
    printf("%x %x", (signed short)y, (signed short)z);)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Output of the first `printf` is as expected. The second `printf` produces undefined behavior.

In C language when you pass a a value smaller than `int` as a variadic argument, that value is always implicitly converted to type `int`. It is not possible to physically pass a `short` or `char` variadic argument. That implicit conversion to `int` is where your "sign extension" takes place.

For this reason, your `printf("%x", y);` is equivalent to `printf("%x", (int) y);`. The value that is passed to `printf` is `0xFFFF` of type `int`. Technically, `%x` format requires an `unsigned int` argument, but a non-negative `int` value is also OK (unless I'm missing some technicality). The output is `0xFFFF`.

Conversion to `int` happens in the second case as well. I.e. your `printf("%x", (signed short) y);` is equivalent to `printf("%x", (int) (signed short) y);`. The conversion of `0xFFFF` to `(signed short)` is implementation-defined, because `0xFFFF` is apparently out of range of `signed short` on your platform. But most likely it produces a negative value (`-1`). When converted to `int` it produces the same negative value of type `int` (again, `-1` represented as `0xFFFFFFFF` for a 32-bit `int`). The further behavior is undefined, since you are passing a negative `int` value for format specifier `%x`, which requires `unsigned int` argument. It is illegal to use `%x` with negative `int` values.

In other words, formally your second `printf` prints unpredictable garbage. But practically the above explains where that `0xFFFFFFFF` came from.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down and into smaller pieces:

> Given,
>
> `unsigned short y = 0xFFFF;`

Assuming two-bytes `unsigned short` maximum value is `2^16-1`, that is indeed `0xFFFF`.

> When I print
>
> `printf("%x", y);`

Due to *default argument promotion* (as `printf()` is variadic function) value of `y` is implicitly promoted to type `int`. With `%x` format-specified it's treated as `unsigned int`. Assuming common two-complement's representation and four-bytes `int` type, that means that as most-significant bit is set to zero, the bit patterns  of `int` and `unsigned int` are simply the same.

> But when I print
>
> `printf("%x", (signed short)y);`

What you have done is cast to signed type, that cannot represent value of `0xFFFF`. Such conversion as standard stays is *implementation-defined*, so you can get whatever result. After implicit conversion to `int` apparently you have bit-patern of 32-ones, that are represented as `0xFFFFFFFF`.